# PIC16F88, portb.bit6, and I2C

Tags: pic, i2c

I am having an odd problem with my PIC16F88.  I have an EEPROM connected thru I2C and it works flawlessly until I write to portb.bit6.  From that point on, I start getting garbage from my EEPROM.  I tried explicitly disabling Timer 1, which uses portb.6 for oscillator-out but that did not help.  I tried cutting the trace from the PIC pin (pin 12) so that there is nothing physically connected to it and that did not help.  My C code is simple, either portb.6 = 0 or portb.6 = 1.  Either way, reading the EEPROM thru I2C fails forever more.  The generated ASM code looks fine.  The problem occurs on every board that I have tried it on, so it is not localized to one PCB.  I am mystified.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to post this question here http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that it is necessary to write a zero bit to the SCL and SDA pins every time before writing to any bit in portb.  FWIW, I was bit-banging rather than using the SSP peripheral of the PIC16F88 for the I2C communicaitons.  Thanks to the people on the Yahoo group, Electronics_101, for figuring out this puzzle.